# Plotting data with multiple dependent variables

Tags: plotting

How can I plot a data set which has four sets of $y$ and only one set of $x$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Have you looked up `ListPlot`?

Comment: Something like... `xlist = {1, 2, 3};
ylists = {{2, 4, 6}, {3, 6, 9}, {1, 2, 3}};
ListPlot[Thread[{xlist, #}] & /@ ylists, Joined -> True]
`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xlist = {1, 2, 3};
ylists = {{2, 4, 6}, {3, 6, 9}, {1, 2, 3}};
```

Since `xlist` is just `{1,2,3}` you can let `xlist` be implied

```
ListLinePlot[ylists, PlotLegends -> Range[3]]
```

[image]

If `xlist` is a different interval you can use `DataRange`

```
xlist = {7, 8, 9};

ListLinePlot[ylists, PlotLegends -> Range[3],
 DataRange -> MinMax[xlist]]
```

[image]

Comment: This does not account for irregular x...

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked wonderfully.